# Is there any way to continue loop even if command inside "for" loop fails in jenkins pipeline

Tags: for-loop, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

```
stages {

    stage('Stage1: Exec') {
        agent {
            label 'master'
        }
        steps {
            dir("/opt/exec/") {
                script {     
                    item = params.keys
                    values = item.keys(",")
                    for (String value: values) { 
                                bat "//run a maven command" 
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
        }
```

"params.keys" are values from selection in extended choice parameter. Even if maven command fails inside "for" loop for a value; I want "for" loop to continue further for remaining values rather than saying build as failed. Using CatchError will continue the loop or proceed to next stage?

Comment: why don't you try the catch block and check?

Comment: you could also try adding `bat "<your command> && exit 0"`.  That should work if you do not need to check exit code of your command

Comment: Adding "&& exit 0" was still failing. Using try catch block solved my problem.  Thanks @ShashankV